# Use existing Lightning component in $A.createComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, helper

I wish to make dynamic aura:id's and for that i want to use $A.createComponent, now i already have a component called 'pageComponentCard' that i wish to call but i can't do this.

The code in question:

```
    $A.createComponent(
        "c:pageComponentCard",
        {
            "component":"{!v.cardId}",
        },
        function(newCard, status, errorMessage){
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newCard);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
            }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
            }
        }
    );
```

Both tried with and without the "c:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is at passing attribute value to `pageComponentCard` <s>"component":"{!v.cardId}",</s> `{!v.cardId}` it is used in component markup . you must use `component.get("v.cardId")` to get attribute value.in controller.

```
$A.createComponent(
        "c:pageComponentCard",
        {
            "component":component.get("v.cardId"),
        },
        function(newCard, status, errorMessage){
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newCard);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
            }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The console does generate the following: " Error: Unknown component 'markup://nvmsconfigtool:pageComponentCard'. ", any idea?

Comment: please post a component markup code  `c:pageComponentCard` component.and you cant use  attribute name as `component` it may cause error.